# Python, Preciso de ajuda com Robo

Tags: python, array, json, .net, orientação-a-objetos

```
while True:
    indicators = I_want_money.get_technical_indicators('EURUSD')
    timeframe = 1
    for dados in indicators:
        if dados['candle_size'] != (timeframe * 1):
            inputs = {

                'value:': np.array([]),
            }
            for timestamp in indicators:
                inputs["value"]= string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)
           # print(filtrados)
            #for inputs['value']in e:
                #for inputs in indicators:
                #x = str(dados['candle_size']).split('.')[1][0]
                   # s = ((dados['candle_size']))
                    # if s == 4:
            (print( sorted(set(inputs))))
```

Esse é o codigo do robo q estou tentando fazer porém, não estou conseguindo pegar o resultado do incador consigo printar e botar numa variavel, porém não consigo pegar somente os 2 primeiros digitos que aparecem na lista que me retorna que seria a leitura do RSI, Preciso somente dos 2 primeiros números pra integrar ao resto do bot

Comment: vlw pelo tempo mano mas infelizmente nao deu certo :( brigadao por tenta ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi com 1 `break`:

```
goal="EURUSD"
size=60#size=[1,5,10,15,30,60,120,300,600,900,1800,3600,7200,14400,28800,43200,86400,604800,2592000,"all"]
timeperiod=60
maxdict=40
I_want_money.start_mood_stream(goal)
print("start stream...")
I_want_money.start_candles_stream(goal,size,maxdict)
while True:
    indicators = I_want_money.get_technical_indicators('EURUSD')
    timeframe = 1
    for dados in indicators:
        if dados['name'] != (timeframe * 60):
            inputs = {

                'value:': np.array([]),
            }
          #  for timestamp in indicators:
          #  inputs["value"] = inputs.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)
      #  avemaria = (dados['value'][0])
      #  for schedule_time in dados:

            start = dados['name']
            time.sleep(20)
            end = int(dados['value'])

            if end < 30:
                check, id = I_want_money.buy(5, "EURUSD", "PUT", 1)
                print("start check win please wait")
                print(end, start)
           # time.sleep(120)
            elif end > 69:
                check, id = I_want_money.buy(5, "EURUSD", "call", 1)
                print("start check win please wait")
            # polling_time=3
            # print(I_want_money.check_win_v2(id,polling_time))
            # print(I_want_money.check_win_v3(id))
                print(end, start)
            print("Cancelar entrada", print(end, start))
        break
```